# Jenkins to monitor external cron jobs

Tags: cron, jenkins

We are using a dedicated Amazon Ubuntu ec2 instance as Cron server, which executed 16 cron jobs at different time intervals  i.e,  10 cron jobs in morning 4:15 - 7:15 and the rest @ 23:00 - 23:50. I get the results via email. I want to configure something, which shoots email message at the end of they day listing the cron jobs that are executed successfully and the one that failed.

I have a jenkins configured ubuntu  instance for auto-building Dev, Beta, Staging & Live environments. Can i add these **cron jobs**(*shell scripts*)  as external jobs in the **jenkins** and monitor them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely possible! You can monitor external cron jobs as described here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs

You can also add cron job (-like behavior) to Jenkins by creating a freestyle software project and add "Execute shell" as build process.
It's a bit more convenient since you can also trigger the execution via Jenkins ("Build now").

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to combine the Jenkins [monitor external job project type](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs) with a [matrix project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project). At the very least the former will enable you to monitor the cron jobs individually.

Alternatively you could have the last monitored cron job of the day trigger building a project that checks the status of all the cron jobs (for example by retrieving and comparing the build numbers of the last and the last successful builds) and sends an email accordingly. The [email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) might be useful for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Check the CPAN or do some web digging for shell or perl script for managing cron jobs and extend its behaviour to do some reporting which you can render using HTML. Alternatively write a servlet and a some function calls to do just that.

This becomes your own standalone monitor application, which can sit in jenkins or deployed independently. If you choose to add it to jenkins, then add the reporting HTML file and its scripts to the container holding deployed web files for jenkins, word of advice place your files and script in a separate container.

Add a hyperlink to jenkins index html which will load your reporter. Now reboot tomcat and go from there.

Answer (score -1):

Another option could be to take a look at Cronitor (https://cronitor.io). It basically boils down to being a tracking beacon that uses http requests to ping when a cron job/scheduled task starts and ends.

You'll be notified if your job doesn't run on schedule, or if it runs for too long/too short, etc. You can also configure it to send alerts to you via email, sms, but also Slack, Hipchat, Pagerduty and others.